# Why can't I add my app in the setting.py before making it? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I've been following tutorials and messing around with Django lately.
I'm trying to revise what I've learned and There's a question I would like to ask:

Can someone explain to me why I can't go to my `setting.py` and add the name of my app in the `installed_apps` before actually making it? I'm a bit confused about the concept.
Why is the other way around allowed in the terminal flawlessly and not in this way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to add a thing that doesn't exist yet? What's the point of doing this?

Comment: Uh I see. That's all I wanted to know. I thought I can just add the name first and make the app after. I just read that I can't name a module if it doesn't exist, just what you said! Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run `python manage.py runserver` django tries to load all the installed apps mentioned in the list.

So the app has to be created before adding it to the installed apps, so that django will find the app and load it.

Comment: I tried one without running my server. I still got the error when I tried to add the name before actually making the app.